# How to convert recursion to loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, recursion

I need convert this code to loops , but i have no idea how .

```js
let object = {
  x: 250,
  a: 5,
  b: 5,
  c: {
    ac: 5,
    acd: 10
  }
};

let objectPropertiesSum = object => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const value of Object.values(object)) {
    if (typeof(value) === "number") {
      sum += value;
    } else if (typeof(value) === "object") {
      sum += objectPropertiesSum(value);
    }
  }
  return sum;
};
console.log(objectPropertiesSum(object));
```

Comment: "*I need convert this code to loops*" - no you don't. A recursive approach is perfectly appropriate here.

Comment: @mplungjan This question is not about arrays though, I don't think the duplicate is appropriate

Comment: @Bergi  I understand, but this is my homework

Comment: @KrisKong Then surely you learned in class how to approach this (e.g. with a queue). If you show us your attempt at a solution, we can help you find and fix the problem, but StackOverflow is not a homework service. Please [edit] your question and I'll reopen.

Comment: @Bergi my task was : "to implement function that will count sum of all object properties that are numbers! " And i write this , now i trying to do same but witih loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting stuck? Maybe this can help you get started.

```js
function sumValues(obj) {
  const stack = [obj]
  let sum = 0
  let o, v
  while (stack.length) {  /* as long as there are items on the stack */
    o = /* get an item off the stack */
    for (v of /* obj values */) {
      if (/* v is a number */)
        /* update the sum */
      else if (/* v is an object */)
        /* update the stack */
      else
        /* v is not a Number or an Object */
    }
  }
  return sum
}
```

Comment: thanks, I read detailed about the stack and found out how to use it